# Vector lengths: How to prove this inequality?

Tags: inequality, vectors, normed-spaces

[image]

I plugged in the summations, tried to square both sides but couldn't reach the desired conclusion. I'm not sure what the second vector would be for the Cauchy inequality. Even when I use the vector itself as the second vector, I still don't see how I could do this.

Comment: Did you try using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality?

Comment: Yeah but I'm not sure what the second vector would be.

Comment: How about an all ones vector?

Comment: For the first inequality, note that if $\mathbf{x} = (x_{1}, \ldots, x_{n})$, then if $\mathbf{u}_{k} = (0, \ldots, 0, 1, 0, \ldots, 0)$, where the $1$ is in the $k$ position, then $$\| \mathbf{x} \|_{2} = \| \sum_{k = 1}^{n} x_{k} \mathbf{u}_{k} \|_{2} \leq \sum_{k = 1}^{n} \| x_{k} \mathbf{u}_{k} \|_{2} = \sum_{k = 1}^{n} |x_{k}|,$$ the final because $u_{k}$ is a unit vector in $\| \cdot \|_{2}$.

Comment: @AJY Can you explain why your inequality is true?

Comment: That would be the triangle inequality.

Comment: oh I see, Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\Vert x\Vert_1^2 = \left(\sum_{i=1}^n\vert x_i\vert\right)^2 = \left(\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\vert x_i \vert \cdot1\right)\right)^2 \leq \left(\sum_{i=1}^n\vert x_i \vert^2\right) \cdot \left(\sum_{i=1}^n1^2\right) =\left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i ^2\right) \cdot n = {n\cdot \Vert x\Vert_2^2}$$

Now take the square root on both sides. This gives you the second inequality. Try the first one using similar arguments.

Comment: I understand this part now, but the first inequality can't really be proven using a similar argument because there is not an "n" term. Meaning I can't use Cauchy there.

Comment: Start with $\Vert x\Vert_2^2=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n{x_i}^2$ and try using Cauchy-Schwarz knowing that ${x_i}^2=\vert x_i\vert\cdot\vert x_i\vert$